# Combine 2 dictionary in ansible / jinja2 (simple)

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I want to use ansible to merge below 2 dictionary to become 1.
I have been stucking for few days already. Headache.

I have 2 variables now.

**1. variable "my_directories":**

```
{
    "directoryA": [
        "/bar/foo/file1.txt",
        "/bar/foo/file2.txt"
    ],
    "directoryB": [
        "/bar/baz/file3.txt",
        "/bar/baz/file4.txt",
        "/bar/baz/file5.txt"
    ]
}
```

**2. variable "my_filecontents":**

```
{
    "/bar/foo/file1.txt": "file1Content",
    "/bar/foo/file2.txt": "file2Content",
    "/bar/baz/file3.txt": "file3Content",
    "/bar/baz/file4.txt": "file4Content",
    "/bar/baz/file5.txt": "file5Content"
}
```

i want to merge it to become:

**Result:**

**variable my_result**

```
{
    "directoryA": {
        "/bar/foo/file1.txt": "file1Content",
        "/bar/foo/file2.txt": "file2Content"
    },
    "directoryB": {
        "/bar/baz/file3.txt": "file3Content",
        "/bar/baz/file4.txt": "file4Content",
        "/bar/baz/file5.txt": "file5Content"
    }
}
```

The directories and files could be dynamic.
I tried so many codes but still did not work.

Thank you!

Comment: show us what you have done so far, not just wait for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task below does the job

```
     - set_fact:
         my_result: "{{ my_result|default({})|
                        combine({item.0.key: {item.1: my_filecontents[item.1]}},
                        recursive=True) }}"
       with_subelements:
         - "{{ my_directories|dict2items }}"
         - value
     - debug:
         var: my_result
```

gives

```
   "my_result": {
        "directoryA": {
            "/bar/foo/file1.txt": "file1Content", 
            "/bar/foo/file2.txt": "file2Content"
        }, 
        "directoryB": {
            "/bar/baz/file3.txt": "file3Content", 
            "/bar/baz/file4.txt": "file4Content", 
            "/bar/baz/file5.txt": "file5Content"
        }
    }
```

Comment: i didnt know i can use value in the subelements! my god.

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, it's a very useful pattern "dict2items/with_subelements".